# How do I setQueryTimeout on SimpleJdbcTemplate?

Tags: jdbc, spring, jdbctemplate

The Spring Framework has two similar classes: JdbcTemplate is the old, Java 1.4 class, and SimpleJdbcTemplate is newer, with nicer methods.

JdbcTemplate has a method [setQueryTimeout](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setQueryTimeout(int)), which basically gives me access to a method with the same name on the underlying Statement object.

Is there any way to do something similar with a [SimpleJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcTemplate.html)?

**Solution**: Based on skaffman's answer, I create the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` object myself from a `JdbcTemplate`, so now I can do whatever I want. Code:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbcTemplate();
jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(30);
SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
```

A bit of a mouthful, but gets the job done.

**Update**: This is indeed more complicated than necessary. See the answer.

Comment: Proably more complex than necessary, see my edited answer.

Comment: What is the unit for the query timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SimpleJdbcTemplat`e isn't a replacement for `JdbcTemplate`, it's just a java5-friendly supplement to it, for certain operations which can take best advantage of varargs and generics.

If you look at the source for `SimpleJdbcTemplate`, you'll see that it delegates all of its work to a `JdbcTemplate` object, and so by setting the timeout (or the other options) on `JdbcTemplate`, you implicitly set them on the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` also.

If you're obtaining the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` via `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport.getSimpleJdbcTemplate()`, then the `JdbcTemplate` will already have been wired up correctly.

edit:

For example:

```
public class MyDao extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport {
    public void doStuff() {
        getJdbcTemplate().setQueryTimeout(x);
        getSimpleJdbcTemplate().execute(...);
    }
}
```

The SimpleJdbcTemplate contains the same JdbcTemplate as is retrieved by getJdbcTemplate().

If you don't extend SimpleJdbcDaoSupport, then yes, you need to manually construct a SimpleJdbcTemplate yourself.

Comment: But how do I access the JdbcTemplate thats "trapped" inside the SimpleJdbcTemplate? All I have is access to a JdbcOperations interface, which doesn't have setTimeout. Care to show some code?

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question, you were asking about SimpleJdbcTemplate. Please modify your question to clarify what you actually want.

Comment: No, my comment was unclear. I meant that having a SimpleJdbcTemplate object, all I have is the `getJdbcOperations()` method. There's no `getUnderlyingJdbcTemplate()` method.